# Remove part of an element in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm writing a csv from an API search (JSON format) and I can take what I need, but my csv is quite "dirty":

```
{u'identifier': {u'identifier': u'the_real_identifier'}}
```

I need to have, in my csv file, just the_real_identifier

I know there's the .remove() function but I don't know how to make it works with all this ' and {.

Plus I don't know if it really works inside the csv.write function and/or I'm forgetting something in my code:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as file2:
    wr = csv.writer(file2)
    for result['identifier'] in search1: 
        time.sleep(10)
        wr.writerow([result])
```

Comment: search1 is the definition of the search via API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?: (Test [here](https://repl.it/BDys))

```
d={u'identifier': {u'identifier': u'the_real_identifier'},
   u'identifier1': {u'identifier1': u'the_real_identifier1'}}
res = [value[key] for key,value in d.items()]
print(res)
# ['the_real_identifier', 'the_real_identifier1']
```

Comparision works like this:

```
if(res[0]=='the_real_identifier'):print("identified")
if(res[1]=='the_real_identifier1'):print("also identified")
```

Or, if you want all results:

```
for item in res:
    print(item)

#the_real_identifier
#the_real_identifier1
```

As requested in the comment:

```
csv1 = "identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4"
csv2 = [['identifier3'], ['identifier1'], ['identifier4'], ['new_item_4']]

data = [item.strip() for item in csv1.split(",")]

for item in csv2:
    real_item = item[0]
    if real_item not in data:
        #this is a new one, we could add it to data
        data.append(real_item)


print(", ".join(data))
#identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4, new_item_4
```

Comment: Yes, it is really good! I ask you just one thing: is there a way to cut also the ' and the [ ]?
That's because then I need to make a comparison with other clean identifiers
Thank a lot!

Comment: Well, this is just a list of elements, you can access them with res[0] and so on. comparision example added.

Comment: yes sorry, I meant I need to compare this list with another list in another csv, but "clean". It's like this:  


    csv1 = identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4  
    csv2 (from API) = ['identifier3'], ['identifier1'], ['identifier4']  


I was thinking about using difflib, it can recognize it anyway?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what you mean, but i'll try anyway.